# Get border style with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I need to get a border style of an element. I tried the following code:

```
sample = page.execute_script("
  var x = window.document.querySelector('#{path}');
  a = window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue('border');
  return a;
")                     
puts sample
```

It's printing null.

(Note: Border of the element is - Solid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your previous questions, I am assuming you are using selenium-webdriver.

The native selenium-webdriver element has methods to check computed styles - [Element#css_value](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#css_value-instance_method).

If you have a page HTML of:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p style="border-style:solid;">A solid border.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can get the border style using:

```
puts page.first('p').native.css_value('border-style')
#=> 'solid'
```

Notice in the code that:

1. Capybara locates the desired element using `page.first('p')`
2. `native` is used to get the selenium-webdriver element
3. `css_value` is used to get the computed style. Note that the css_value method has to be passed the paramater 'border-style' not the shorthand 'border'.

**Update:**

For your specific example:

1. It seems that if you use the shorthand "border" property, the "border-style" property will be blank. Instead, you have to use the specific "border-bottom-style", "border-left-style", etc. properties.
2. Since you know the id of the element, you can get the Capybara element using `page.find_by_id('option')`

Considering the above, you can check the computed border style using:

```
puts page.find_by_id('option').native.css_value('border-bottom-style')
#=> "solid"
puts page.find_by_id('option').native.css_value('border-left-style')
#=> "solid"
puts page.find_by_id('option').native.css_value('border-right-style')
#=> "solid"
puts page.find_by_id('option').native.css_value('border-top-style')
#=> "solid"
```

Comment: I have a page HTML of:      
                                                           
>> <html>
    <body>
         <div id="option">BLACK</div>
    </body>
<html>

Css:
#option
{
border: Solid;
}

For this page, how can i take the value of border?

Comment: For some reason, 'border-style' does not have a value when using the 'border' shorthand property. Instead, you will need to check the individual borders - 'border-bottom-style', 'border-bottom-style', etc. Answer updated with code specific to your example.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the poltergeist driver? @JustinKo

Comment: @安杰帅, I do not have experience with the poltergeist driver. You will have to try it out. If it does not work, I would suggest creating a new question.